# Simplifying repeated onclick events for different selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `img` elements with ID's. When I click the element, I change the `img src` like this

```
$("#employee").on("click", function(){
    var x = $(this);

    var y = $(this).attr("src");

    if($(this).attr("src") == "images/employee.svg")
    {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/employee_selected.svg");
    }

    else
    {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/employee.svg");
    }
});

$("#team").on("click", function(){
    var x = $(this);

    var y = $(this).attr("src");

    if($(this).attr("src") == "images/team.svg")
    {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/team_selected.svg");
    }

    else
    {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/team.svg");
    }
});

$("#product").on("click", function(){
    var x = $(this);

    var y = $(this).attr("src");

    if($(this).attr("src") == "images/product.svg")
    {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/product_selected.svg");
    }

    else
    {
            $(this).attr("src", "images/product.svg");
    }
});
```

This code seems to be awfully repetitive and I was wondering if there was a way to do this in a single `.on click function` using something like a switch statement.

How could I simplify this into a single statement?

Comment: Combine all the selectors into one. The only difference between all 3 is the image names which are easily resolved from the `id` of `this`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may consider giving them each a class name and use that selector instead of the ID selector. Much easier for grouping: `$(".className").click(function(e){ });` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".svg").on("click", function() {
    var x = $(this);
    var non = "images/" + x.attr("id") + ".svg";
    var sel = "images/" + x.attr("id") + "_selected.svg";

    if (x.attr("src").indexOf("_") < 0) {
      x.attr("src", sel).toggleClass("selected");
      console.log(sel);
    } else {
      x.attr("src", non).toggleClass("selected");
      console.log(non);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <img id="employee" src="images/employee.svg" class="svg image" />
  <img id="team" src="images/team.svg" class="svg image" />
  <img id="product" src="images/employee.svg" class="svg image" />
</div>
```

We can extract the `SRC` of the element that was clicked and based on a specific condition, perform a specific action. This works for all elements with the class selector, `svg`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are OK with collections.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img id="employee" src="images/employee.svg" class="svg" />
  <img id="team" src="images/team.svg" class="svg" />
  <img id="product" src="images/product.svg" class="svg" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

  var images = {
    employee :  ['images/employee.svg', 'images/employee_selected.svg'],
    team :      ['images/team.svg', 'images/team_selected.svg'],
    product :   ['images/product.svg', 'images/product_selected.svg']
  };

  $(".svg").on("click", function(e) {
    e.target.setAttribute("src", ( e.target.getAttribute("src") === images[e.target.id][0] ) ? images[e.target.id][1] : images[e.target.id][0]);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uo7rhnbf/2/

Answer (score 0):

More advanced scenario from my side, but also more flexible.

---

**How to invoke?**

```
toggleElementsOn({
  selectors: [ 'body', '.btn1' ],
  event: 'mouseover',
  keyword: '_add_something_to_image_src_path'
})
```

Additionally as you can see, **event** and **keyword** is configurable.

---

**Implementation:**

***Vanilla JS***

```
function toggleElementsOn ({ selectors, event = 'click', keyword = '_selected' }) {
  /**
   * Get elements based on passed selectors
   * @param {Array<String>} args
   */
  const getElements = args => args.map(elem => document.querySelector(elem))
  const elems = getElements(selectors)

  elems.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener(event, (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const target = e.target;
    const matcher = new RegExp(`(${keyword}|[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\.[a-z]{3})$`, 'g');

    target.src = target.src.replace(matcher, (match, filenameOrPostfix, ext) => {
      return filenameOrPostfix === keyword ? ext : `${filenameOrPostfix}${keyword}${ext}`;
    });
  }));
}
```

***jQuery*** version

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function toggleElementsOn ({ selectors, event = 'click', keyword = '_selected' }) {
    /**
     * Get elements based on passed selectors
     * @param {Array<String>} args
     */
    const getElements = args => $.map(args, elem => $(elem))
    const elems = getElements(selectors)

    $.each(elems, (key, elem) => {
      $(elem).on(event, (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const target = $(this);
        const matcher = new RegExp(`(${keyword}|[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\\.[a-z]{3})$`, 'g');

        target.attr('src', target.attr('src').replace(matcher, (match, filenameOrPostfix, ext) => {
          return filenameOrPostfix === keyword ? ext : `${filenameOrPostfix}${keyword}${ext}`;
        }));
      })
    });
  }
});
```